# passing logical variables to Fortran subroutines

Tags: fortran, logical-operators, subroutine

I have the following simple piece of Fortran code.

```
program main
    implicit none
    call flag_test(.TRUE.)
    subroutine flag_test(flag)
        implicit none
        logical,intent(in) :: flag
        if(flag) then
            print*, "flag is true"
        else 
            print*, "flag is false"
        end if
    end subroutine flag_test
end program main
```

I want to understand how to pass logical variables in an if-statement. This piece of code gives  the following errors:

```
main.F90:4:1:

  subroutine flag_test(flag)
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
main.F90:5:15:

   implicit none
               1
Error: Duplicate IMPLICIT NONE statement at (1)
main.F90:6:28:

   logical,intent(in) :: flag
                            1
Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)
main.F90:12:4:

  end subroutine flag_test
    1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
main.F90:7:9:

   if(flag) then
         1
Error: Symbol ‘flag’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Could you please help me understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: @francescalus Understood. It works. Thanks!!